# Разброс времени выполнения

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вот случайная функция, она возвращает своё время выполнения. И это время каждый раз разное, разброс в целых 2 раза (от 1.5 до 3 секунд).

```
from time import time
from random import randint
def funk():
    t = time()
    diction = dict(zip(range(10), 'qwertyuiop'))
    for _ in range(1000000):
        _ = diction[randint(0, 9)]
    return round(time()- t, 4)
print([funk() for _ in range(10)])
# [1.5676, 1.6232, 1.5675, 1.5516, 1.5576, 1.5513, 2.9011, 3.958, 3.9729, 3.9717]
```

Почему так происходит? Можно решить, что играет роль поиск в словаре, то, сколько значений интерпретатор перебирает перед возвратом значения, но нет, миллион итераций заглушает это.

В чем причина?

Comment: Во-первых, код должен быть кодом, а не картинкой

Comment: Во-вторых, на вашем компьютере одновременно работает ещё около сотни программ, и каждая из них может в условно случайные моменты времени отобрать время процессора на себя и тем самым замедлить python

Comment: (Я бы попробовал запустить у себя и посмотреть, какой разброс у меня и правда ли другие программы могут влиять настолько сильно, но вы ж не дали код)

Comment: В-третьих, скорость программы замеряют сотнями, а то и тысячами повторений и берут среднее значение, а не делают выводы из десятка вызовов.

Comment: @Эникейщик ну там внутри всё-таки цикл на миллион вызовов, получаемые значения и так в каком-то смысле средние

Comment: А, точно. Я внутрь не заглядывал :) Я бы проверил как оно на телефончике, но жалко, что кода нет. @andreymal

Comment: переделал в код. суть как раз в том, что цикл из миллиона одинаковых действий выполняется за разное время, это и странно. программ открыто больше не было, только идлешка.

Comment: @MichaelTetelev программ не может не быть больше не открыто. Как минимум у вас есть рабочий стол (это тоже программа, ага), менеджер окон, центр обновлений, аудиосервер, с десяток-другой прочих системных служб и возможно ещё антивирус — и все они могут значительно влиять на получающийся разброс

Comment: На моём компьютере получилось `[1.2134, 1.2109, 1.2105, 1.2142, 1.2058, 1.2166, 1.2172, 1.2185, 1.2156, 1.2202]` — можно считать, что у меня разброса нет